# How to configure Capistrano to abort deployment when running a local script fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, capistrano3

Given a simple web application deployed via Capistrano. There's a build process in a script `build.sh` called from `deploy/deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :build do
    system "cd web && ./build.sh"
  end
  before :starting, :build
  ...
end
```

How would I configure Capistrano to ***abort*** my `cap prd deploy` immediately upon receiving an exit code 1 from the `system` command inside of the block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system` is the wrong choice of command.

Inside of the `task :build` block, use the `sh` method instead of `system`.

```
sh "cd web && ./build.sh"
```